# Getting Javascript Variable or value from another file

Tags: javascript

I have a file `./js/onload.js` and inside this I have this code.

```
$('#fb5-book').turn({
                display: DISPLAY,
                duration: 600,
                acceleration: true,
                elevation: 50,
                page: nrPage,
                when: {
                    first: function (e, page) {
                        $('.fb5-nav-arrow.prev').hide();
                    },

                    turned: function (e, page) {

                        Book_v5.currentPage = page;  //Do not delete this, other function use this.
                        
                        if (page > 1) {
                            $('.fb5-nav-arrow.prev').fadeIn();
                            //$('#fb5-about').hide();
                        }

                        if ((page == 1 && RTL == 'false') || (page == $(this).turn('pages') && RTL == 'true')) {
                            $('#fb5-about').css('z-index', 11);
                        }

                        if (page < $(this).turn('pages')) {
                            $('.fb5-nav-arrow.next').fadeIn();
                        }
```

After `Book_v5.currentPage = page;` If I add `alert(page)` or `console.log(page)` I can get alert and data in console.

I have a index.php file. In that I want to create a variable `let pageNumber=1` and the value of pageNumber will be change acording the `page` value in `./js/onload.js` How can I do this?

I tried this in `./js/onload.js`

`let pageNumber=page;`

and in `index.php` inside `<script>` tag I tried to call the `pageNumber` it's not working. I am a newbie in JS.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to share the value of the page variable between your JavaScript files. Here are three options:

You can use a global variable. In ./js/onload.js, you can define a global variable like this:

```
window.pageNumber = page;
```

Then, in index.php, you can access the value of pageNumber like this:

let pageNumber = window.pageNumber;
You can use the window.postMessage method. In ./js/onload.js, you can send a message to the parent window like this:

```
window.parent.postMessage(page, '*');
```

Then, in index.php, you can listen for messages from the child window like this:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
  let pageNumber = event.data;
});
```

You can use a library like PubSubJS to publish and subscribe to events. In ./js/onload.js, you can publish an event like this:

```
PubSub.publish('pageNumber', page);
```

Then, in index.php, you can subscribe to the event like this:

```
PubSub.subscribe('pageNumber', function(msg, pageNumber) {
  console.log(pageNumber);
});
```

Comment: I have tried all 3, but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the answer.

Inside `index.php`

```
<script>
let pageNumber = 1;

function updatePageNumber(newPageNumber) {
  pageNumber = newPageNumber;
}
</script>
```

and inside `onload.js` I have added the function

```
turned: function (e, page) {
  // other code here
  updatePageNumber(page);
}
```